# Converting images to different file formats using GeoTools

Tags: convert, geotiff-tiff, java, geotools, jpg

After searching through GeoTools documentation and following their tutorials, I have failed to find a class that can convert images to different format (for example translate a .tif to .jpg).

Does GeoTools have a Translate function, like GDAL, in some other git repository?

Comment: No, you just read them in and then write them out in the new format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
   AbstractGridFormat format = GridFormatFinder.findFormat(input);
    //working around a bug/quirk in geotiff loading via format.getReader which doesn't set this
    //correctly
    Hints hints = null;
    if (format instanceof GeoTiffFormat) {
        hints = new Hints(Hints.FORCE_LONGITUDE_FIRST_AXIS_ORDER,Boolean.TRUE);
    }

    AbstractGridCoverage2DReader reader = format.getReader(input,hints);
    GridCoverage2D grid = reader.read(null);

    File out = new File("test.jpg");
    Iterator<ImageWriter> writers = ImageIO.getImageWritersBySuffix("jpg");
    ImageWriter writer = null;
    while(writers.hasNext()) {

        writer=writers.next();
        break;
    }
    writer.setOutput(new ImageOutputStreamAdapter(new FileOutputStream(out)));
    writer.write(grid.getRenderedImage());
```

Note JPG isn't a geographic format so you need to drop down to the default ImageIO to write them out.

Comment: Ian Turton: can you please elaborate over '*you need to drop down to the default ImageIO*'? As you guess, your snipped does not find any suitable ImageWriter  for 'jpg' images.

Comment: works fine on my machine. The comment is just that you won't be using the Enhanced ImageIO that GeoTools uses.

Comment: Ok.. ..so mine is not a lib issue. I'm getting *Process failed during execution javax.imageio.IIOException: Illegal band size: should be 0 < size <= 8* The GridCoverage2D I'm trying to dump is a float32 that fits perfectly in a GeoTiff.. ..but doesn't fit in a 'jpg'. Any clue?

Comment: I think you need to ask a new question - make sure to add the gdalinfo output on the input file to the question as well as your code